# Bulb inside the prism

Tags: optics

What if a source of white light is within the prism itself. Let's say it emits a thin beam of white light. Now the speed of different wavelengths is different but it is not being refracted at a surface (atleast until it emerges from the other side), so what will happen to it? Will it stay together as white light only? And what happens once it crosses the other side?

This just popped up in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply: the white light, assuming it hits the face of the prism at an angle other than perpendicular, will be spread over angles of exit by color (so long as the prism glass has a nonuniform index of refraction).
You are correct that there will be some phase lag inside the prism, so if you were to generate a very short pulse of "white" light and had sufficiently fast measurement tools you might see different color components exiting at slightly different times. When you have a continuous source, of course, there's no "time zero" to measure against.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Thanks